# Tell me the config to move src/pages/api directory to src/ in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, project-structure

In **Next.js**, i want to move `src/pages/api` directory to under `src/` as like `blitz.js`.
namely, directory structure follows like this

```
src
|- pages
|- api
```

However, I couldn't find a way to set it up to realize.
If you know of any, please let me know the URL or documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the next.js documentation, [tests](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/51e0752f8710ee0eebc68c87a50cf61b5c8082c0/test/integration/production/test/index.test.js#L325), and [code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/203f43c1fe740c78bd0d9aee90563ca739a8ef38/packages/next/lib/constants.ts#L18) there is no such config. So if you want to use next.js api you need to use the structure: `pages/api`. But if you want to just change api route then you can do it using `rewrites` config. Read [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/9081)

**next.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    rewrites: [
        { source: '/api/:path*', destination: '/my-api/:path*' }
    ],
};
```